# Modified Composite pattern / Food, Recipes and Subrecipes

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

I'm having troubles implementing the Composite Pattern correctly (to make it the most efficient).

There are two entities involved: **Basic Food** and **Recipes**. They are to be parsed from a **CSV file**.
A Basic Food object would contain a letter (to denote if it's a food or recipe - in this case f), name, calories, fat, carb and protein. The Recipe would contain the letter r and the name of the recipe.

I'm aware that the **Basic food** should be a corresponding leaf, and the **Recipe** would be composite. However, the lines in a CSV row of the recipes file, which denote a Recipe can contain more **food** in a way that it has name(s) and count (number of servings) pairs. The name(s) can be both a Basic Food and a (Sub)recipe, which raises to question how to make an optimal solution?

My first though is to make the composite hold a `List<Food>` to store it's composites, and have a property `Map<Food, Double>`. What would be the easiest way of checking if we're dealing of a certain type of food and provide CRUD-like functionalities? The program implementation is in Java.

```
E.g. b, FoodName, 1, 2, 3, 4 (basic food) 
E.g. r, RecipeName, foodOneName, foodOneCount, foodTwoName, foodTwoCount, ...
```

Comment: If you have a `Map<Food, Double>` do you really need a `List<Food>` at all? It seems redundant. My suggestion is to start coding by simplifying the requirements: implement basic food first, then recipes without sub-recipes, then sub-recipes without servings, etc. If you get stuck along the way, post your code.

Comment: Because a recipe can contain Food and Recipe, you need Map<String,List<RecipeItem>> where String is the name of the Recipe, RecipeItem is Map<Object,Integer>, and Object is either Food or Recipe and Integer is the number of Object to include.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible model. First, let's define an abstract class that represents an ingredient (can be either a basic food or a recipe):

```
abstract class Ingredient
{
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

A basic food is an ingredient so it extends Ingredient:

```
class BasicFood extends Ingredient
{
    int calories;
    int fat;
    int carb;
    int protein;
}
```

A recipe is also an ingredient and it contains a list of items. Each item contains an ingredient and a quantity:

```
class Item
{
    Ingredient ingredient;
    int quantity;
}

class Recipe extends Ingredient
{
    List<Item> items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement the Composite pattern you need an interface that is implemented by both `Food` and `Recipe` in order to treat them uniformly.

This interface, for example, might expose the methods to get the characteristics of a food or recipe:

```
public interface Component {
    String getName();
    double getCalories();
    double getFat();
    double getCarb();
    double getProtein();
}
```

For `Food`, the implementation of that interface is simple since it just matches its getters:

```
public class Food implements Component {

    private String name;
    private double calories;
    private double fat;
    private double carb;
    private double protein;

    public Food(String name, double calories, double fat, double carb, double protein) {
        this.name = name;
        this.calories = calories;
        this.fat = fat;
        this.carb = carb;
        this.protein = protein;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public double getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }

    @Override
    public double getFat() {
        return fat;
    }

    @Override
    public double getCarb() {
        return carb;
    }

    @Override
    public double getProtein() {
        return protein;
    }
}
```

In `Recipe`, like you said, we can use a `Map` to save its components and quantities.

To implement the `Component` interface we could return the sum (multiplied by the quantity) of the characteristics of all its components, that could be both food and sub-recipes.
But due to polymorphism we don't have to treat them differently, which is the goal of the Composite pattern:

```
public class Recipe implements Component {
    private String name;
    private Map<Component, Double> components;

    public Recipe(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        components = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public double getCalories() {
        return componentsSum(Component::getCalories);
    }

    @Override
    public double getFat() {
        return componentsSum(Component::getFat);
    }

    @Override
    public double getCarb() {
        return componentsSum(Component::getCarb);
    }

    @Override
    public double getProtein() {
        return componentsSum(Component::getProtein);
    }

    private double componentsSum(Function<Component, Double> function) {
        return components.entrySet().stream()
                // get the requested characteristic and multiply it by the quantity
                .mapToDouble(entry -> function.apply(entry.getKey()) * entry.getValue())
                .sum();
    }
}
```

In `Recipe` we also add the CRUD operations to add/remove/update its components, for example:

```
public Double add(Component component, double quantity) {
    // if already present, add the quantity
    return components.merge(component, quantity, Double::sum);
}

public Double remove(Component component) {
    return components.remove(component);
}

public Double update(Component component, double quantity) {
    // if present, replace the quantity
    return components.computeIfPresent(component, (k, v) -> quantity);
}
```

You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` of both `Food` and `Recipe` in order for these methods to work correctly. In my examples we should only consider the variable `name`.

And then some code to test it:

```
// foods
Component f1 = new Food("f1", 1, 1, 1, 1);
Component f2 = new Food("f2", 2, 2, 2, 2);
Component f3 = new Food("f3", 3, 3, 3, 3);

// recipe with only food
Recipe r1 = new Recipe("r1");
r1.add(f1, 2);
r1.add(f2, 1);

// recipe with food and sub-recipe
Recipe r2 = new Recipe("r2");
r2.add(f3, 1);
r2.add(r1, 2);

// prints 11.0 11.0 11.0 11.0
System.out.println(r2.getCalories() + " " +r2.getFat() + " " + r2.getCarb() + " " + r2.getProtein());
```